# ViewState errors on 3 servers

Tags: hibernate, iis, timeout, viewstate

We have 3 servers setup.. Two of which have almost identical IIS configuration and one server which is setup slightly different.

All 3 servers are running the same application however on the two replica's when a person hibernates their PC and re-attempts logon (Say 20 minutes later) one would get a ViewState Error.

This only happens on 2/3 servers.. I've compared the configuration of all three servers and am struggling to find reasoning behind the viewstate errors.

On the two replica (Not clustered, just replica configuration running two separate app instances) servers the below error is generated after the user has hibernated their PC and attempted a page refresh on return:

```
********** 18/11/2014 22:01:40 **********

Inner Exception Type: System.Web.UI.ViewStateException

Inner Exception: Invalid viewstate.

                Client IP: HIDDEN

                Port: 61727

                Referer: HIDDEN

                Path: /WERWER/Loginpage.aspx

                User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

                ViewState: /wEPDwUJMTU3NDQ3OTA5D2QWAgIDD2QWBgIFDxYCHgRUZXh0BQczLjEuNC4zZAIJDxAPFgIeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2QPFgICAQICFgIQBQtBc3RyYVplbmVjYQUBMWcQBQtBc3RyYVplbmVjcQUBMmdkZAILDw9kDxAWAWYWARYCHg5QYXJhbWV0ZXJWYWx1ZWQWAQIDZGRkfcrsQ9t3t1viPYtGtlL9zhltvqca0XJ8+sAMNb9FJhc=

Inner Source:

Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException

Exception: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

 

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Source: Application_Error - Global.asax

Stack Trace:

   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState)

   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose)

   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose)

   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

   at ASP._aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\appdir\405a4e54\e0bdc3da\App_Web_qp5t5y2q.3.cs:line 0

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Another Occasion::

********** 16/10/2014 11:29:06 **********

Inner Exception Type: System.Web.UI.ViewStateException

Inner Exception: Invalid viewstate.

                Client IP: hidden

                Port: 63887

                Referer: hidden

                Path: HIDDEN

                User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

                ViewState: /+kH3Hw9hzBkL2Oug==

Inner Source:

Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException

Exception: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

 

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Source: Application_Error - Global.asax

Stack Trace:

   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState)

   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose)

   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose)

   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

   at ASP._aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\405a4e54\e0bdc3da\App_Web_uhtljwwn.1.cs:line 0

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Could anyone perhaps help ?

**FYI: Heres how the end-user describes the situation:**

> "Ok – I checked on the server and hibernated my PC with the browser
> window open at the log in page.
>
> Restarted the computer 30 mins later,  logged back in and got the
> exception message that I have seen on the other replica server…

Someone I work with noted that I could resolve the problem by setting a fixed machine key - Which machine key do I set to 'fixed' ? There appear to be three Levels (A machine key you can set from the top level IIS structure, a key you can set from the website level, and a key you can set from the virtual sites level??)

Which key do I change? And what is the need for 3 individual 'Machine Key' configurations?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just change whichever you choose. But make sure on all servers application sees the same machineKey.

There are multiple levels of configuration so that you can set it on

- machine level
- all applications level
- one application level

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although from what I'm understanding from your reply, you are suggesting we are running in a web farm environment? This is not the case.

Comment: Oh, you understand right, I misunderstood you. Can you verify that application did not restart/recycle between user visiting it/hibernating/visiting it again? I think it did.

Comment: Hi Perry, I've just posted an answer on this question because I and my collegue were able to fix this in the end.. However problem is.. We've done something but not quite sure on how it's going to impact on us.. Could you check out my reply if possible, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Right.. Herewith an update which I'd really appreciate a reply to if possible.

**Issue:**
When idle for 20 minutes and when the user attempts to log back in, he/she is presented with a ViewState Error.

**Initial understanding:**
Something is not read when the app pool restarts whilst under the identify of ‘Webadmin’

**Extract from Microsoft Support Thread:**
When the application pool is running under a user account, the above keys are not generated leading to an intermittent invalid viewstate error.

**Solution:**
Specify a manual machine key in web.conf, this fixed the issue.

**Outcome Expectation:**
To be able to gasp why when the application pool is running as a user we get a viewstate error when using AutoGenerate / Unique for each application options in ‘Machine Key’ configuration.

1)  Are there any security risks involved when specifying a static key in the web.conf

2)  Why would a machine key not be able to generate when running the app pool under a different user.

3)  Why does the issue not occur when running as the DefaultAppPool User?

Comment: From what I understand unless you specify MAC in config it is generated on every application start. So when user visits your site Viewstate is encoded with MAC1. Then your application restarts and generates MAC2. Now when user visits site again he's ViewState can't be validated because it is using different MAC. MAC1 != MAC2 so ASP.NET thinks someone tampered with ViewState.